# Raise event on PenDrive Attch and Detach

Tags: c#, windows

In my application i want to raise event on pen drive attach and detach event.
I have used following code to raise event.

```
private ManagementEventWatcher watcherAttach;

private ManagementEventWatcher watcherRemove;        

watcherAttach = new ManagementEventWatcher();
watcherAttach.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
watcherAttach.Query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
watcherAttach.Start();


watcherRemove = new ManagementEventWatcher();
watcherRemove.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventRemoved);
watcherRemove.Query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 3");
watcherRemove.Start();


// this are events
void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
     // code to execute
}

void watcher_EventRemoved(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
   //code to execute
}
```

But the problem is that both events are raised twice and my code is not fully executed in both of the events can any one suggest me how to overcome from this?

Comment: use try catch inside your code and find the exception in your code.

Comment: but it not showing any error.

Comment: Yes there is an error tnx.

Comment: but still the event is raised two times

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to unsubscribe from an event, then do your job and subscribe again. Chances that some other device will be plugged in when your're unsubscribed, are small. I did it similar way, when dealing with double keystrokes on keyboard.

```
// this are events
void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
watcherAttach.EventArrived -= new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
     // code to execute
watcherAttach.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
}

void watcher_EventRemoved(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
watcherRemove.EventArrived -= new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventRemoved);
   //code to execute
watcherRemove.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventRemoved);
}
```